# High Performance Extensible Logging (hpel)

Tags: servlet-filters

I'm running WebSphere Application Server z/OS 8.5.0
I activated High Performance Extensible Logging (hpel)
We use the appName extension to filter log records.
is the appName extension only available for log entries written once the application has been initialized? 
We have seen that in some cases, the appName extension is
not available in the log record, mostly during application startup.

Answer (score 0):

The appName is part of the thread context information that is set up when requests are processed by the server.  Assuming you're just missing the appName from server startup messages, what you're seeing is normal.  If you're missing the appName from web container handled requests, that would be unexpected.

For example, if you enable runtime trace for `*=info:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.*=finer` and look at the logs related to the isclite application (which is the admin console web app), you'll see that the messages that appear during init of the app do not have an appName header, but trace entries related to servlet hits to the admin console itself do have an appName header.